# How to create a LXD container on a machine and register it in MAAS?

Tags: maas, lxd

Is it possible to deploy a bare-metal machine with MAAS and create some LXD instances that are registered in a MAAS zone?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to lookup:

[Getting Started with LXD](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/28/getting-started-with-lxd-the-container-lightervisor/)

Also, you could specify in a .juju/openstack.cfg file like:

```
nova-compute:
  virt-type: 'lxd'
```

...combined with a deployment like:

```
juju deploy --config=.juju/openstack.cfg nova-compute
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible right now. MAAS itself isn't aware of LXD containers or of the LXD daemon so containers won't show up in MAAS.

You can certainly deploy LXD on top of MAAS managed servers by using JuJu or even doing it manually, but LXD will not be added to MAAS as say libvirt can be. Nor does it really make sense either since LXD containers can't be PXE-booted and so can't run the MAAS installer.